# Use custom field for participant search in event registration?

Tags: civievent, custom-fields

We have some custom fields for our members.  When manually adding a participant to an event, I’d like to be able to search by those custom fields when searching for a contact.  How can I do this?

[image: example search]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any UI config to add filters in 'Refine search' dropdown. However you can add filters via custom extension by implementing entityRefFilters hook.

Alternatively you can use Advance search >> Select contact(s) >> Event registration (from task actions).

HTH

Pradeep